Why can't I change FastAPI application in function call?
I have FastAPI project, in my main.py I'm initializing app globally and then including routes or doing anything else with my app in the main function (which calls only when if __name__ == '__main__'). So I've noticed the problem that when I'm including my router in the main function, it doesn't see my routes when receiving the request; although, when printing app.routes, I can see my router there. But when I'm including the router globally after creating app, everything works fine. The question is why does it work like this?
Here are some code snippets, which show it:

This one works fine
main.py:

from core.router import router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)


def main() -> None:
    ...
    config = container.resolve(Config)
    s = config.server
    s.port = args.port or s.port
    s.host = args.host or s.host
    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host=s.host,
        port=int(s.port),
        reload=(config.mode == "local"),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



But this one doesn't. I'm receiving not found error when sending a request to any of my routes (although the route path is correct), and also my routes don't show up in the openapi docs.

main.py:
from core.router import router

app = FastAPI()

def main() -> None:
    ...
    # including router inside function
    app.include_router(router)
    config = container.resolve(Config)
    s = config.server
    s.port = args.port or s.port
    s.host = args.host or s.host
    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host=s.host,
        port=int(s.port),
        reload=(config.mode == "local"),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I expect that when I'm including routes in the main function, or changing app state, it should apply correctly. For example, if I'm changing app state in the function, it just has no effect (when I'm trying to get property which I set from req.app.state, I'm receiving attribute error).

When uvicorn.run is called with “main:app”, uvicorn will import the app object from your main.py before executing any code in the if name == “main” block.
At this point, the application instance is created, but your routes are not yet registered, as app.include_router(router) is in the main() function and has not been executed.
FastAPI requires routes to be registered before the application starts serving requests.
When uvicorn loads the app object, it sees the application without the routes included (since main() has not been called), resulting in a “Not Found” error for all routes

Got it! Thank you for explanation. So should i do that kind of interactions with app globally in my main file?

Yes, it's usually best to perform interactions with your FastAPI app at the global level in your main.py file to ensure that everything is properly configured before uvicorn imports and starts serving the application.

I've posted an answer that takes up the procedure described in the FastAPI doc.

I recommend using:
ex: src/main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(
    title="Fast API",
    description="My API",
)

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"message": "Welcome to API"}

And then run the app:
fastapi dev src/main.py or fastapi run src/main.py as recommended in the doc
